# Break from for each loop in xslt

Tags: xslt, for-loop, break

I have to break from `for-each` loop if `@PercentOfAmountActive` is not equal to 0 or 100.

This is my XML:

```
<SamplePointSet Id="1" StartDate="2012-01-01T04:00:00Z" CalendarId="1" Cyclic="6" ForAttribute="0" ObjectId="0" ProbabilityFunctionId="0" TableNumber="0" TimePeriodId="4" ParentId="1">
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="1" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="2" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="3" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="4" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="5" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="6" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="7" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="8" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="9" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="10" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="100" Sequence="11" SamplePointSetId="1" />
    <SamplePoint NumberOfActiveTimePeriods="30" PercentOfAmountActive="0" Sequence="12" SamplePointSetId="1" />
  </SamplePointSet>
```

Below is xslt code

```
<xsl:for-each select=".../CM:SamplePointSet/CM:SamplePoint">
  <xsl:variable name="varActiveTimePeriod" select="./@NumberOfActiveTimePeriods * $varMultiple"/>
  <xsl:variable name="varPercentOfAmountActive" select="./@PercentOfAmountActive"/>

  <!-- . . . some Condition To break if (percent of amount active) not 0 or 100 -->

  <xsl:value-of select="CMXsltExtObject:SetRecurenceRule($varActiveTimePeriod, $varPercentOfAmountActive, $varCalendarFrequency)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid for-each loops in XSLT. Instead, where possible, apply your nodes to templates, using XPath to target only those nodes that are suitable.

You can achieve the break effect by applying templates only to those nodes...

- whose `@PercentOfAmountActive` attribute is equal to 0 or 100
- none of whose preceding siblings have a `@PercentOfAmountActive` attribute which is not equal to 0 or 100.

Here's a simplified example, which you can run at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/AMuPU0).

**XML**

```
<root>
    <node attr='0'>hello 1</node>
    <node attr='100'>hello 2</node>
    <node attr='0'>hello 3</node>
    <node attr='100'>hello 4</node>
    <node attr='1'>hello 5</node>
    <node attr='0'>hello 6</node>
    <node attr='100'>hello 7</node>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='root/node[(@attr = 0 or @attr = 100) and not(preceding-sibling::*[@attr != 0 and @attr != 100])]' />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='node'>
    <li><xsl:value-of select='.' /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Only the first four nodes are output, simulating the 'break' effect once we hit a node that was unsuitable.

Answer (score 2):

An xsl:for-each instruction is not a loop, it is a mapping from an input sequence to an output sequence. What you describe in procedural terms as a "break" from the "loop" is actually saying that you want the mapping to select only those items in the input sequence before the first one that has at attribute value not equal to 1 or 100.

The most efficient solution is probably to use sibling recursion:

```
<xsl:template match="SamplePointSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SamplePoint[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SamplePoint">
  ... some processing ...
  <xsl:if test="@A = 1 or @A = 100">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::SamplePoint[1]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want that if any value other than 0 or 100 comes than get out of this for each and not further processed...